# Dynamic video grid layout for react native agora

Tags: react-native, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm using react native agora for `videocall`. I need the video grid layout as same as `whatsapp` video grid layout for group call. I tried may ways but failed. please help me for find a solution.

Comment: did you find any solution for the same?